# How do I use float enums with a Jcombobox in Java

Tags: java, swing, enums, jcombobox

I have an enum class that uses floats for its values e.g.

```
public enum Size {

    SMALL(10.50f),MEDIUM(12.35f),LARGE(15.90f);

    private float value;

    Size(float value){ 
        this.value = value;
    }
    public float getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

I want to use this enum to 'generate' the list that will be used for a Jcombobox where the user will select one of the sizes.

```
ddSize.setModel((Size.values()));
```

I'm trying to use the code above, however I get the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: Size[] cannot be converted to ComboBoxModel<String>
        ddSize.setModel((Size.values()));
```

I need a way for me to be able to use the float enums without getting this error, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setModel` took a `ComboBoxModel<E>`, so you can use `DefaultComboBoxModel` to fill the `JComboBox` like so :

```
ddSize.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(Size.values()));
```

---

to make sure it works :

```
IntStream.range(0, ddSize.getItemCount())
        .forEach(index -> System.out.println(ddSize.getItemAt(index)));
```

**Outputs**

```
SMALL
MEDIUM
LARGE
```

Comment: I end up getting this error when I do this,
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DefaultComboBoxModel
  location: class newOrderForm

Comment: @UnknownPerson are you sure you import `import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;`